# Number of ways to divide $N$ identical things into groups of size at least $K$

Tags: combinatorics

We are given $N$ and $K$, we have to find number of ways to divide $N$ identical items into groups of size at least $K$.

**Example 1:** $N = 4, K = 2$

**Answer:** $2$

The given divisions are $(4)$ and $(2,2)$

**Example 2:** $N=6 , K= 2$

**Answer:** $4$

The divisions are $(6)$, $(2,2,2)$, $(4,2)$ and $(3,3)$.

**NOTE:** we consider $(4,2)$ and $(2,4)$ as the same.

Comment: This is the same as the number of ways to partition into *at most* $k$ parts.

Comment: please provide a link or the formula....i am not so pro in combinatorics

Comment: Part of the problem is that it is not easy to solve even for the trivial case $K=1$.  Then the answer to your problem is called the *partition function* for $N$.  There's no nice formula (the nicest one I can think of is that it's the coefficient of $X^N$ in $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{1-X^k}\right)$).

Answer (score 3):

There's no nice formula.  As I said in the comments, there's no nice way even to compute the answer for the trivial case $K=1$.  If $K=1$, then the number of partitions is just the total number of partitions of $N$, up to reordering.  We write this as $p(N)$.  If you want a sort of formula for $p(N)$, it's the coefficient of $X^N$ in the infinite series:

$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{1-X^k}\right)
$$

This does not give an efficient method for computing $p(N)$, however.  In fact, the best way to try and work out what $p(N)$ is, is by considering partitions where each set has size at most $K$, as you are asking for.

Write $p(K, N)$ for the total number of partitions of $N$ items into sets of size at most $K$, up to reordering.  For example, $p(1, N)=p(N)$.  The following three facts are quite easy to show:

1. $p(K, N)=0$ if $K>N$
2. $p(K, N)=1$ if $K=N$
3. (the most important one) $p(K, N)=p(K+1, N)+p(K, N-K)$ otherwise.

After you've shown these three facts (only the third is at all tricky), you can find $p(K, N)$ for arbitrary $K, N$ using the following algorithm: draw up a table of values for $p(K, N)$ for $N=1,2,\dots$ and $K=1,2,\dots$, and then fill in the table using the three rules above until you reach your desired value.

To get you started, you can immediately fill in some of the table by putting $1$s along the diagonal (where $N=K$) and $0$s below it (where $K>N$).  Then you can tackle the case $N=K+1$: using rule (3.), you get

$$
p(K, K+1)=p(K+1,K+1)+p(K,1)
$$

You can use this to fill in the diagonal just below the diagonal you've filled with $1$s.  Then just keep going: you should be able to work out how to go on from here!

Comment: I have a doubt. After working this out on pen and a paper, considering the case of p(K, K+1)=p(K+1,K+1)+p(K,1), this implies that we are trying to divide the K+1 elements into groups such that each group is of at-least size K. But this is not something which is possible, because then we can divide groups in the fashion of (K,1) which violates our needs (the second group having only single element).
So isn't the p(K,K+1) case invalid in such a case?