# Different ways to divide identical objects into groups

Tags: combinatorics

This question has been asked in different forms but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430213/number-of-ways-to-divide-n-identical-things-into-groups-of-size-at-least-k) came close but not close enough).

Assume I have 4 marbles. There are effectively only 5 ways of dividing them into groups of size at least 1 and at most 4:

```
1) o o o o 
2) o o oo
3) o ooo
4) oo oo
4) oooo
```

I am wondering if there is a generalized formula for this? The key element here is that the groups can but not must be the same size and that the elements are identical (i.e. ooo o and o ooo are identical).

Comment: Are you just after the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function)?

Comment: Actually yes, however I'm not sure I understand how to apply the formula for an integer n...

Comment: The partition function famously hasn't got a simple, closed form.  That's why it is so extensively written about. Read the link I suggested, search online for more discussion. Not sure what it is that you are hoping for here.

Comment: Actually that did help! Yours should be the accepted answer, thanks!